# What's the maximum resultset size in Google Cloud SQL? If there is how can it be increased?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have an issue with trying to read data from a google cloud sql database and write it to a google app engine datastore. The read of the database looks like it is not returning all the values it should when the value of entries retrieved is around 210, as i've checked that if it retrieves 189 entries or lower it's able to write all retrieved entries properly, and if it's higher I've achieved it to write at most 209 entries un datastore, although sometimes, it writes less than those ones.

I understand than if million of rows with thousands of columns were returned, yeah, of course, a limit should be stablished in memory usage of the app, but it's not even 300 entries with 5 columns, I've checked how much it would occupy in plain text and it doesn't even reach the 15K, so I think it should be able to deal with this with no problems.

Anyy idea of what might be happening?

Comment: Are you sure that your servlet is not timing out while processing?

Comment: What language are you using? Are you using the native MySQL connectivity (MySQLdb in Python and 'jdbc:google:mysql://' in Java)?